# Efficiency of using CSV file as database

Tags: c#, t-sql, csv

I have a large (350 MB) CSV file that I need to query. I get the data file as a data dump once every day, so I could do some daily processing to this data. Once I have the data, I want to query it at more frequent intervals. I'm wondering how best to do this.

I was thinking that I have two alternatives.

1. Connect with an `OleDbConnection` and then query directly using an `OleDbDataAdapter`, like this

   ```
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + base.applicationRoot + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=CSVDelimited\"");

   OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select something from [{0}]", base.csvFileName), conn);
   ```
2. Transfer the whole csv file, as I get it, into a 2012 sql server database table, and then query from that sql table instead.

What is the better approach. Or, how inefficient is it to use a CSV file as a database (read-only)?

Comment: 350MB? You could easily load the entire document into memory and query in-memory. But how efficient it could be depends on data structure, types of queries you're going to run and how you'd represent in as in-memory collection.

Comment: How often do you have to query the table? Would indexes help?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, when you say in-memory, could you be more specific? The issue is that I would get frequent web requests for specific rows of data, and reading the whole file into memory every time would take a lot of time.

Comment: @attila, indexes might help. I'm not sure exactly how the data is going to be formed yet (I'm not creating the csv file, just downloading it and querying it). The querying is a web part, so that would have to be pretty fast, and be ready for fairly high volume. Is OleDb slow?

Comment: Ole db is great. The problem is the database engine you use for cvs access. Importing into sql server is fast and can usually keep the whole table in memory as along as there isn't any memory contention.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't Ole db the database engine I use for csv access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would insert the csv into a database for more powerful query capabilites. 
If you're using SQL server you can even bulk insert the csv using a standard bulk insert command.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: The bulk insert might be interesting. Would you set that up as a stored procedure and call it from the code?

Comment: A stored procedure is definitely a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

If its an offline solution, you could use SQLite instead of Sql Server. That would give good performance compared to a CSV, but with the overhead of constructing it once a day.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually do need the data server side as well. BTW, isn't there a size limit on SQLite? At least, some users might not like me bloating 350 MB on their client.